# Base64 / SVG HTML image is not displayed

Tags: html, image, svg, base64

I tried to use this icon

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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5324e483b5f25ab4badb7c52c102103e"/>
```

from this page
http://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/baggage-on-conveyor-band_48876

I just copy and paste the html code (Base64 / svg)  into my website.
But the icon is not displayed. why?

Here is an example 
http://jsfiddle.net/Lsr4s/

**UPDATE:**
I dont get it. I copy another image/icon and it is broken too, but the base64 code has no "=" jsfiddle.net/TYb59 Is the flatIcon.com page so buggy?

Can I fix this images/icons?

Comment: I would recommend downloading the image uploading it yourself and putting it in the link.<img src="http://i.imgur.com/fqAsZoj.png"/> I did it for you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fKt8G/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The base64 code that you have copied is broken. Close to the end there is `==` in the middle of the code. That is a filler that is placed at the end of a base64 code.

Remove the part after `==`, and it will work fine.

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"/>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lsr4s/2/

#### Edit:

Downloading the svg file from the site and base64 encoding it gives exactly the same result. If there is no signature that you can use to easily fix the code, that is what you would need to do.

I used C# code like this to base64 encode the image to a text file:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"d:\temp\baggage19.txt", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\temp\baggage19.svg")));
```

Comment: I dont get it. I copy another image an it is broken too ... but the base64 code has no "=" http://jsfiddle.net/TYb59/
Is the flatIcon.com page so buggy?

Comment: @Peter: Perhaps it is. The base64 code only has `=` or `==` at the end if the number of bytes isn't evenly divisiable by three. Without it, there is no easy way to tell if the code is truncated or appended with garbage. If you give me the link to that page, I could get the svg file and base64 encode it to see what it should be.

Comment: Download as SVG file and encode to base64. Works! Thanks!

Comment: You could use an icon provider that has a CDN like iconrequest.com

Comment: NOTE: It's important that the base64 code contains `+xml` after the `svg` part.

Comment: Super Working Fine :)

Answer (score 22):

So, after trying a few things (I really needed to display SVG as src="data:"). I came across a couple key points:

- You don't have to encode it as base64, pure svg can be used, this makes it much more readable, as well as smaller both in length and after gzip. It's also much easier to test/debug/edit.
- It is **imperitive** to have the `xmlns` attribute in the `svg` tag regardless of whether you use base64, or utf8. That was the piece that eluded me the most.

Now without further ado, a simple example:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><line x1='0' y1='0' x2='200' y2='200' style='stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2'/></svg>" />
```

For completeness: http://jsfiddle.net/y1akw1fd/

Comment: Hello @mateuscb,

as per you above solution, i need you help in detail

i want to add image element also in svg

here is what i want : <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><image overflow='visible' enable-background='new' width='50' height='50' xlink:href='https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png'></image><line x1='0' y1='0' x2='200' y2='200' style='stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2' /></svg>" />

Please help 

Thank you

Comment: @mateuscb Most Compatible Answer

Comment: Hi, I can't get it right (base64& utf8) this svg works https://www.svgviewer.dev/s/UqUzUIaK but not in an img tag http://jsfiddle.net/juanmf/70cznmLe/8/.

Comment: @jimbirch that is true, but in many cases (it was in mine) you are tasked to render user uploaded content.  Lots of ways to do this also, but we found this to be the best for our case. But great reminder that if you own the html, you can just use <svg> tags.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today and came to the following conclusion:

Usage of the `<embed>` tag as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) had the best compatibility over the tested browsers (Firefox, Safari, Chrome on Mac OS). The above code would be written as:

```
<embed src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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5324e483b5f25ab4badb7c52c102103e"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

did not displayed,  according to https://www.base64decode.org/ your  base64 contains error

in the end you add `==5324e483b5f25ab4badb7c52c102103e` - that had an incorrect data !

So i advise you use some tool to correctly convert image data  to base64 string. like in  https://www.base64encode.org/  and all will be ok !

Answer (score -4):

I would recommend downloading the image. Upload it yourself and putting it with the link.
Look at my comment above. Not letting me post jsfiddle..

Comment: ...when measuring the performance of hundreds of thousands of mobile page views, that loading images using a data URI is on average 6x slower than using a binary source link such as an img tag with an src attribute!

Comment: That's true! no doubt about that